# Difference between static partitioning hypervisors and separation kernel / microkernel?

Tags: embedded, partitioning, virtualization, hypervisor, microkernel

I am trying to get an understanding of virtualization approaches.
This [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10155684) describes *static partitioning hypervisors*.
In this survey [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06875) the category *separation kernels and microkernels* is explained as a possible virtualization approach.

Some of the given examples for hypervisors appear in both of them and to me it seems like those two categories describe the same thing.

Are those synonyms or are there some aspects that differentiate static partitioning hypervisors and separation kernels?

Also what is the relationship between separation kernel and microkernel? Are all separation kernels also microkernels?

I have read these two papers and tried to find an explanation from other sources online. While each paper explains these concepts individually the relationship between those terms remains unclear to me.

Answers for similar question only explain kernel, microkernel and hypervisor.